# Problem With Javascript Form Interaction

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I'm having an issue with a javascript interaction on a site, and I can't figure out what's going on.

The basic gist of this site is this:  One single .php page that has multiple includes contained within hidden divs.  When the next or back buttons are clicked one of the divs becomes active (visible), and it contains questions with image links for answers.  When one of these links is clicked a javascript function is called which is supposed to set a value in a hidden form field equal to the value that's passed to the function from the link.

I've got no idea why it's not working.  I've done stub testing using alerts, and everything is being passed correctly.  Occasionally it'll work on one question, but never all of them.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  You can find the source code here:

http://3-1.faile-test.appspot.com/kilt_page.php

Comment: Can you explain in more detail about what isn't working?

Comment: @rlb.usa the value is not being set in the hidden form, i gave up when it spat alerts at me

Comment: I can turn the alerts off.  I thought they might be helpful in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Lawrence is correct, the values aren't being set in the hidden form.  I need those values to process the rest of the (unbuilt) application.

Comment: Ahh, I see how to alert users now - 
@Lawrence Cherone - the alerts are now off, if you'd care to take another look.  It's the links (not the text input fields) that I'm worried about.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has this issue, here's how I solved it:

I added default values to the hidden form inputs.  So, instead of:
`<input type='hidden' name='answer_name' value='' />`

I have:
`<input type='hidden' name='answer_name' value='default' />`

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you are setting the wrong value in the hidden fields.

For example if I enter a company name "foo inc", the field is set as:

```
<input type="hidden" value="company_name" id="company_name_answer">
```

Should it not be?

```
<input type="hidden" value="foo inc" id="company_name_answer">
```

I think that the change_selection function is wrong, you have:

```
function change_selection(selection, answer)
{
    var selection = selection;
    var answer = answer;
    document.getElementById(answer).value = selection;
}
```

It should presumably be...

```
function change_selection(selection, answer)
{
    document.getElementById(answer).value = document.getElementById(selection).value;
}
```

Comment: Argh enter key...I'm concerned about the links - 
<a id="ops" onclick="changeClass('ops');change_selection('ops', 'service_answer');" class="">Commercial Operations</a>

The changeClass function works every time.

Comment: Sorry Fraser, that's what I meant by doesn't work = )  I haven't written the function for them yet.  Right now the function for the text fields is just a copy of the link function, and the link function passes static values of the item ID and the form field ID.  I kept that in there (instead of alerts) so that I could see the function *should* still work for the links.

Comment: I dont think I understand, when I click that link it sets the hidden input as so: <input type="hidden" value="ops" id="service_answer">

Comment: Hm...so it IS working for you?  If you click multiple links does it work?  If you reload the page does it continue to work?  What browser are you using?

Comment: Also, please check links on the other pages, if you don't mind.  The operations page appears to work for me as well now (although I haven't changed anything...)

Comment: It looks like it might be saving the answers between page refreshes.  The first time I click on the operations page, the value doesn't get saved.  When I refresh, there is a value there.  When I click again, it changes to whatever I picked, and I can continue to save unless I force a full refresh (clearing cache).  It's the same for the other pages.  They won't work the first time through, but WILL work most of the time after the page has been refreshed once?

Comment: Yes it works on all the pages - I tried using Chrome 13.0, IE 9 and Firefox 6 both on Vista and windows 7. I can't reproduce the code failing at all. It all works as expected. I can't reproduce the error you are having so I don't think I can help more, sorry.